# Understanding plurisubharmonic functions

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Suppose $D$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{2}$ and $u(z)$ is a plurisubharmonic function on $D$. We write $z=(z_{1},z_{2})\in \mathbb{C}^{2}$. Is it true that if we fix $z_{2}$, the function $z_{1}\mapsto u(z_{1},z_{2})$ is subharmonic or identically $-\infty$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true up to  [the definition of a plurisubharmonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plurisubharmonic_function) because the set $(z_1,z_2)$ with fixed $z_2$ is a complex line $(0,z_2)+(1,0)\cdot z_1$.

Comment: Thanks. But what if $(0,z_{2})$ does not belong to $D$?

Comment: I don't think the definition of subharmonicity  given by Wikipedia is exact in the following point: the function $z\mapsto u(a+bz)$ is subharmonic (or $\equiv-\infty$) for all $a\in D$ and $b\in\mathbb{C}^{n}$, and not $a\in \mathbb{C}^{n}$.